# The same Unicode character sometimes appears as solid black and sometimes a colored icon

Tags: unicode, icalendar, emoji, html-entities

I offer a team calendar via Google Calendar to our sports club. It contain all match appointments for several teams and sports (like soccer, tennis, dart...).
I put Unicode icons at the beginning of the subject like a dartboard and a house for a dart match at our home location and a car for outside.

Like this:  DC Flight Control - Team Dart Donkies

On Smartphones the icons appears as a colored image.
In browsers on a Win7 system as a solid black icon.
On my Win10 system also as colored image.

Same Google-Account, same view, same Google-Settings...

Is this a windows depending thing? Anybody can explain?

Comment: Relevant link: [It All Started With Emoji: Color Typography on the Web](https://css-tricks.com/it-all-started-with-emoji-color-typography-on-the-web/)

Comment: No support in Win7, only 4 more months before everybody can say "not my problem".  https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/06/using-color-fonts-beautiful-text-icons/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a font-depending thing

Windows 7 was so old and existed long before emojis came into existence and became common, therefore it doesn't have the appropriate font to display the colored emojis. And even if you install some newer fonts then it still can't render the colored characters because its font renderer doesn't support such a new feature. Initial [support for color fonts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/color-fonts) was added since Windows 8.1, but only fonts with COLR/CPAL tables. Other colored font formats were later supported in Windows 10

> An update for the Segoe UI Symbol font in **Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2** brought a ***subset of the monochrome Unicode set*** to those operating systems. […] Windows 8 and higher supports the full Unicode emoji characters through Microsoft's Segoe UI family of fonts. […] As of **Windows 8.1 Preview**, Segoe UI Emoji font supplies ***full-color pictographs***
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji#Microsoft_Windows

The [same thing occurs on Linux](https://www.kirsle.net/make-emoji-work-in-linux) where only a few modern distros have emoji support by default. [Ubuntu has only included colored fonts since version 18.04](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/11/ubuntu-finally-long-last-time-support-color-emoji), which means if you use the young 2-year-old Ubuntu 17.10 you'll see the black characters

Some applications like Firefox use *their own font renderer* and therefore can show colored emojis even on non-supported OSes. For example [Firefox can display those characters on Windows 7 and Linux](https://superuser.com/a/1173928/241386) but Chrome and IE can't (not sure if Chrome was updated to support that or not):

> Added a built-in Emoji set for operating systems without native Emoji fonts (Windows 8.0 and lower and Linux)
>
> [Firefox 50.0 release notes](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/50.0a2/releasenotes/)

It's also possible that [someone hates colored characters and disable it completely](https://superuser.com/q/1111369/241386)

Comment: I guess, thats the right answer. This post itself shows black icons on older Win versions and colored ones on win10. So, its not depending on Google Calendar! Thx for clarifying...

Comment: not only on Win7. If your user uses Linux then they may still see black characters

Comment: It is possible to update this font (Segoe UI Emoji) on older Windows versions, the 2018 (v1.29) seguiemj.ttf is available in KB4032236 Office 2016 update, and has 12,189 glyphs (compared with 2,344 in v1.02 as in Windows 8.1). Color support may not be available.